# Does anyone know how to draw dotted lines in openGL SE using fragment shader

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, fragment-shader

I tried to use this tutorial:
http://korkd.com/2012/02/15/dashed-lines/#comment-32

but I don't know what are: sourcePoint, mv and a_position.

If you have any other suggestions please help...

Answer (score 2):

`sourcePoint` is the starting point of the line in world space. It is a `uniform`, which means that the same value is used for the entire draw operation.

`mv` (also a `uniform`) is the modelview matrix, which transforms a point from model space to world space, so that `a_position` is using the same coordinate system as `sourcePoint`. It is the same thing as `u_modelViewProjectionMatrix` but without the projection transformation.

`a_position` is a `varying`, which means that the vertex shader sets a value for each vertex, and then the fragment shader gets an interpolated value for each pixel. So the value the fragment shader receives will be the position of the pixel in world space.

If you still are confused, I suggest reading up on how shaders work. It can be a tad confusing at first.

Comment: Can you please show me working code of this.I am bit confused. Thanks in advance.